# Cant find error in my code : C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array). I have written this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int findIndex(x, lastAns, N) {
    return ((x == !lastAns) % N);
}

void query_1(int x, int y, int N, int lastAns, std::vector< std::vector<int> >& v) {

    v[findIndex(x, lastAns, N)].push_back(y);

}

void query_2(int x, int y, int N, int* lastAns, std::vector< std::vector<int> >& v) {

    *lastAns = y % (v[findIndex(x, *lastAns, N)].size());
    cout << *lastAns << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int N, Q;
    cin >> N >> Q;

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
    std::vector<int> buff;
    int queryType;
    int lastAns = 0;
    int x, y;

    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<N-1; ++i) {
            buff.push_back(0);
        }

        v.push_back(buff);

    }

    for(int i=0; i<Q; ++i) {
        cin >> queryType;
        cin >> x >> y;

        if(queryType == 1) {
            query_1(x, y, N, lastAns, v);
        } 

        else if (queryType == 2) {
            query_2(x, y, N, &lastAns, v);
        } 

        else continue;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc

I havent come across this error before. When I run the code through gdb, I get this :

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff74ab418 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Someone will suggest you to use debbuger sooner or later...

Comment: Is there particular reason using ugly macro instead of normal or template function?

Comment: No reason. I just thought for a simple enough calc, a macro would suffice.

Comment: not related to the error, but in `query_1` you push into a vector that is passed by value

Comment: Macro should be used only if there is no other way or different solution is too complex. Good luck debugging your macro. You may learn this hard way.

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks for that one.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: bad_alloc probably because you request too much memory

Comment: please dont fix bugs pointed out by others once you have posted the code and got comments/answers. In the best case this is confusing (in the worst case you invalidate answers)

Comment: What this statement `(x == !lastAns) % N` suppose to do? It does not have  much sense (mod operation on 0 or 1)

Comment: I really don't understand why you use `(x == !lastAns) % N`.  There is no need for the `%N`.  The expression `x == !lastAns` will evaluate to 0 or non-zero.  Think about the `1 % N` or `0%N`.  Does it make sense to take the remainder of 1 or 0 when dividing by N?

Comment: The problem states index calculation as `((x ^ lastIndex) %N)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:

```
   for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<N-1; ++i)  // <<<<<< some little mouse got here
```

EDIT:

Explanation:
You have created infinite loop, where `j<N-1` is always `true`. This means, you push new elements into vector until no more memory is available, hence the run-time error.

Comment: Yeah, answers the question `What is the problem in my code?`

Comment: Maybe you should make that more clear?

Comment: Yup that removed the bad_alloc error. Thanks for explaining too.

Answer (score 0):

This function may be a cause of an error:

```
int findIndex(x, lastAns, N) {
    return ((x == !lastAns) % N);
}
```

First off, the parameters are missing their types.

Next, the expression

```
!lastAns
```

will evalute to zero or non-zero.
Which means that you are comparing an integer, `x`, to zero or nonzero:
`(x == 0) or (x == 1)`
The result of the above expressions is either zero or non-zero.  Let's assume 1 for nonzero.  You get the final expression

```
`return 0 % N;` or `return 1 % N`;
```

The final return value is 0 or 1.  The `N` variable doesn't matter, because the only significant values are 0 or 1.  You can't have N as zero (which you don't check for), and when N is 1, you still get 0 or 1.

So your expression:

```
v[findIndex(x, lastAns, N)]
```

will be `v[0]` or `v[1].

Comment: The missing function parameter types were result of poor edit of the question. It was a macro before.